# read variable into file used in process substitution

Tags: bash, awk

In the below `bash`, I am trying to extract the last "non-empty line" using the `awk` below and store it in a variable `filename`, that is later used in a `bash` process substitution.

```
while IFS= read -r  line; do
mapArray["${line%_*}"]="$line"
done < <(tail -n +3 /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/$filename/analysis.txt)
can not read file at `/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API//analysis.txt`
```

**awk to extract $filename**

```
# extract folder for variable filename
filename=$(awk 'END{print}' /home/cmccabe/medex.logs/analysis.log)
```

analysis.log `always the last line of this file`

```
R_2017_03_10_15_11_27_user_S5-00580-35-Medexome
R_2017_03_14_10_35_42_user_S5-00580-36-Medexome
R_2017_03_14_13_13_34_user_S5-00580-37-Medexome
```

**bash tried**

```
while IFS= read -r  line; do
mapArray["${line%_*}"]="$line"
filename=$(awk 'END{print}' /home/cmccabe/medex.logs/analysis.log)
done < <(tail -n +3 /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/$filename/analysis.txt)
```

executing the `awk` by itself

```
cat name.txt
R_2017_03_10_15_11_27_user_S5-00580-35-Medexome
R_2017_03_14_10_35_42_user_S5-00580-36-Medexome
R_2017_03_14_13_13_34_user_S5-00580-37-Medexome

awk 'END{print}' name.txt
R_2017_03_14_13_13_34_user_S5-00580-37-Medexome
```

Comment: The error message clearly shows that `filename` is *not* set (or if it is, it is set to the empty string).

Comment: "always the last line"? Or just the last *non-empty* line? It'd help if you could make the sample self-contained.

Comment: if I execute the `awk` and look at the output the correct line is extracted, but it seems that it is not read into the variable `$filename`.  Thank you :).

Comment: That is to say, if you can reproduce `awk 'END{print}'` emitting an empty line of output with input *you show us how to create in this code*, then others will be able to reproduce your problem. For instance, an attempt (which fails, because `awk` does the right thing): `awk 'END{print}' < <(printf '%s' $'one\ntwo\nthree\n')`

Comment: I... doubt that. Doubt that rather a lot. Does `bash -x yourscript` back it up?

Comment: sorry it is always the last non-empty line or is supposed to..  Thank you :).

Comment: Might I suggest you edit the question, then, to ask how to extract the last non-empty line from a file (and maybe take out everything that's unrelated to that? If we *know* the problem is with extracting the filename, there's no point to including questions that spawn from incorrect use of that empty filename in the question; see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I made an edit to the post.  Thank you :).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138553/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-chris).

Comment: Waaaitaminute. You're reading from `$filename/analysis.txt` as your outer loop, then populating `$filename` **inside** that loop. It should be pretty obvious why that doesn't work: If there's no `filename` set **before the loop is started**, it'll never successfully read a line and get into the body (where you're setting `filename`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is trying to read from `API/$filename/analysis.txt` **before** it sets `filename`.

That assignment needs to be done outside the loop, and complete before it starts.

```
declare -A mapArray ## needs to be associative for the below to work

filename=$(awk 'END{print}' /home/cmccabe/medex.logs/analysis.log)
while IFS= read -r  line; do
  mapArray["${line%_*}"]="$line"
done < <(tail -n +3 "/home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/API/$filename/analysis.txt")
```